# Convert array of objects to object of objects and assign specific keys

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of questions about this but i couldn't find exactly what i want.

i have an array of objects like this

```
[{id:1}, {id:2}]
```

i want to assign the id as a key and the object as a value

```
{
    "1": {
         id: 1
     },
     "2": {
         id: 2
     }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried ? And where are you getting `id: 3` from ? Can we have some more context please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object with keys according to the `key` param:

```js
const keyBy = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o[key]] = o;
  
  return r;
}, {});

const arr = [{id:1}, {id:2}];

const result = keyBy(arr, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

And if you want it to be more functional, use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to replace the accumulator:

```js
const keyBy = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((r, o) => ({ ...r,  [o[key]]: o }), {});

const arr = [{id:1}, {id:2}];

const result = keyBy(arr, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.reduce`:

```js
const input = [{id:1}, {id:2}];
const output = input.reduce((accum, { id }) => {
  accum[id] = { id };
  return accum;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You're reusing the same `accum` across calls, so this is just a weird way to write a foreach loop.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an accumulator to be reused across iterations (usually)? `reduce` is more appropriate than `forEach` when turning an array into something singular like an object

Comment: No, the whole point of an accumulator is that it changes across calls. Otherwise you could just do `const output = {}; for (const { id } of input) { output[id] = { id }; }` (hope I got the JS syntax right).

Comment: The accumulator references the same object across calls, but its properties change - that's what's happening in both mine and yours. I prefer array methods to `for` loops. If you prefer `for`, that's your choice, but that doesn't mean `reduce` is invalid

Comment: OK, then `input.forEach(({ id }) => { output[id] = { id } })`. The point is that `reduce` adds no value here. You're only using it for its side effect of iterating over the array.

Comment: @melpomene I see your point, in that it's not a specific solution for this specific problem, but there is no reason not to take advantage of its properties ?

Comment: ... Heck, you could write the same code using `filter`: `const accum = {}; input.filter({ id } => { accum[id] = { id }; });`. Or `find`. But if the only thing you care about is iterating over the elements, then `forEach` (or a plain loop) are the most appropriate. Anything else is obfuscation or may indicate a misunderstanding of the algorithm.

Comment: @melpomene Using `forEach` like that requires mutating something external, which is usually not preferable when there's an alternative. The  entire point of `reduce` is to be able to create an object (or something) *all at once*, functionally. If the goal is to turn an array into anything singular (like an object), `.reduce` *is* the most appropriate method to use.

Comment: You could, but reduce is designed to run a function over each element of the array.. by definition. What you've written is actually over verbose anyway as filter will create the accum already.. The only reason I could honestly push against it would be if you needed more performance, in which case usually a for loop is going to be more efficient. Other than that, I find this argument pedantic!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Your code is not functional exactly *because* it mutates something external (the `{}` object created outside `reduce`). You're not turning an array into a single object, you're creating the object empty *first*, then modifying parts of it piece by piece. See Ori Dori's answer for a truly functional (but also kind of inefficient) version.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be (es6):

```
const newObject = {};
myArrayWithObjects.map(singleObject => {
    newObject[singleObject.id.toString()] = singleObject;
    return true;
});
```

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy) can also help you with this:

```
const newObject = _.keyBy(myArrayWithObjects, function(singleObject) {
    return singleObject.id.toString();
});
```

And https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr is definitely worse a glimpse. But would be overkill for this task, I guess.

Comment: nice suggestion but staying on the pedantic tone, Map is more for when you want to **transform elements in an array**.

Comment: I was about to say, why `return` anything from the map function when you're not doing anything with the result anyway? And then you could just use `forEach` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right. I often process arrays and object side by side. But this is not the case here 

Comment: @melpomene map function is meant to return something, isn’t it? Will work without, but ya....maybe it was just the wrong approach like Pogrindis announced.

Comment: @Matthi If you don't have an explicit `return` statement, it acts like `return undefined;`, so you'd end up with `map` returning `[undefined, undefined]`. But since you don't even look at `map`'s return value, it doesn't matter. This is why I suggested `forEach`: It also iterates over the array, but it doesn't build up the return array that your code doesn't need.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, you are right. I guess it sneaked into my mind, because of some linter in Create React App.